# Stretching an image within a <li> with css IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to stretch an image used in an `<li>`, as the text within the `<li>` increases the size of the image size isn't big enough to increase along with the `<li>`. I do not want to repeat the image also. The below code works with all the latest browsers with CSS3 but I need the image to stretch for all versions of internet explorer between 6 and 9. How can this be done?

```
.Menu li a.active, .Menu li a.active:hover
{
    background-image: url('/images/11_MenuSelected.png');
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; 
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

Comment: "All version of IE less than 9" I think you mean all versions of IE greater than... 6? 7? 8?

Comment: @BenRoux - I think he's saying the current code works for all browsers, including IE9. He's looking for alternative solution for IE < IE9 since they do not support background-size.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I am saying is that a lower limit is required to give a complete answer. The solution will vary in IE 5 vs IE 8

Comment: "all versions of internet explorer less than version 9" is dogmatic. Very few people are currently using anything less than 7.

Accorsing to w3schools.com, in March 2012, only 2.5% of users in their stats were on IE7, and 0.9% were on IE6. They don't even report on versions 5.5 and below.

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @Ben Roux - True. I misunderstood your previous comment. I'd assumed IE7 would be the oldest browser he'd be supporting but I suppose that isn't a given. ;)

Comment: @sethflowers - I still believe Ben's question is prudent as many large organizations have a much different internal browser demographic than the general web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for IE6-IE8.

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/11_MenuSelected.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

The catch is that the src is relative to the HTML document, not to your stylesheet.  So it behaves differently than your typical style rule.  You'll probably want to change this so it is that the src is relative to the root so it can be used with documents of varying path structures.